# Lack of info about a new flag (--no-enable-managed-prometheus) for disabling a default enabled Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, gcloud-cli

As you can see in the attached picture, we received an email from [tag:The Google Kubernetes Engine Team] that there will be a new flag for disabling default Prometheus in cluster

> after March 15, 2023, all newly created Google Kubernetes Engine standard clusters will have Managed Service for Prometheus in-cluster components deployed by default. To deploy clusters without Managed Service for Prometheus, it can disable it on new GKE standard clusters by adding the flag `--no-enable-managed-prometheus` when creating a new GKE standard cluster, e.g.
> `gcloud container clusters create --no-enable-managed-prometheus`

I searched in the [release note page](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes)  but I could not find it, I would like to know is it an upcoming feature or a released feature?
If it is an existing feature, where can I find some documentation about it?

Is there anybody have more info about this email?
[email from The Google Kubernetes Engine Team](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mS9z.png)

Comment: Those are upcoming changes on 15 march as mentioned in email, if you have an existing cluster it won't be running there if you are creating a new cluster after 15th of march it will be there by default what i guess. Currently, it's an optional feature to enable in GKE.

Answer (score 0):

Google Managed Prometheus (GMP) has been available for GKE for a while now.  Currently, you need to [enable GMP on your GKE standard clusters](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/setup-managed#enable-mgdcoll-gke) (it is enabled by default on Autopilot clusters).  You can enable it via the UI, CLI, Terrform, etc.  Via the CLI, you would use the `--enable-managed-prometheus` flag to enable it.  If you want to disable it later, you can use the `--no-enable-managed-prometheus`.

The note you got is saying that effective on Mar 15, GMP will be automatically enabled by default on new clusters so you'll now need to disable it if you don't want to use it.  We should be publishing a release note around March 15 as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, From March 15, when I run a `create` command for a new cluster I should add  `--no-enable-managed-prometheus` flag , if I don't want to have a default GMP. For example: `gcloud container clusters create  --no-enable-managed-prometheus` . Right?

Comment: Will this flag `--no-enable-managed-prometheus` be available from release 422.0.0 ?

Comment: It's actually available now.

Comment: And yes to your first question.

Comment: Thanks. You said that this flag `--no-enable-managed-prometheus` is available now but I cannot find it in [the release note page](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#42100_2023-03-07) . I need to make sure from which version this flag is enabled. Would you please specify the version number?

Comment: It's actually been available since https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#kubernetes_engine_9.  When using gcloud, almost every `--enable-` flag has a corresponding `--no-enable-` flag as well.  For some reason, we don't document this though.